# Weka Euclidean Distance

Tags: java

I have two Weka instances which, when printed, look as follows:

```
0.44,0.34,0.48,0.5,0.3,0.33,0.43,cp
0.51,0.37,0.48,0.5,0.35,0.36,0.45,cp
```

I am trying to obtain their distance using the in-built Euclidean Distance function. My code:

```
EuclideanDistance e = new EuclideanDistance(neighbours);

        double x = e.distance(neighbours.instance(0), neighbours.instance(1));
```

Where neighbours is an object of type Instances and the objects at indexes 0 and 1 are the two instances I referred to.

I am slightly confused because x is returned with value 1.5760032627255223 although, by doing the calculation separately, I was expecting 0.09798. cp is the class label, but earlier in my code I did specify  `data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);`

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Weka's `EuclideanDistance` metric normalizes the ranges to compute the distance. If you don't want that, call `e.setDontNormalize(true)`.

Comment: Thanks, and I assume categorical features are automatically dealt with too right?